# Chart.js v3: how to allow tick label overflow?

Tags: chart.js, linechart

I recently upgraded from Chart.js v2 to v3. I am drawing realtime line charts with a time-based x-axis that scrolls right as time passes.

In Chart.js v3, as my x-axis tick labels begins to approach the left edge of the chart, it resizes the graph to fit the full label. As shown in the attached image, this creates an empty gap on the left-side of my chart. In Chart.js v2, it would not resize the graph, and would instead allow the label to overflow the canvas.

[image: Chart.js x-axis tick overflow]

My x-axis options are:

```js
{
  type: 'time',
  axis: 'x',
  min: minDate.getTime(),
  max: maxDate.getTime()
  time: {},
  ticks: {
    minRotation: 45,
    maxRotation: 45,
    source: 'labels'
  }
};
```

Is there any option to restore the old behavior and allow the tick labels to overflow?

Answer (score 1):

You could format the first tick to be empty string, using [ticks.callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats)

```js
{
  type: 'time',
  ticks: {
    callback: (value, index) => index === 0 ? '' : value
  }
}
```

[example in codepen](https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/qBjRgvj)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to get the desired behavior using the `afterFit` callback.

```js
{
  type: 'time',
  afterFit: (scaleInstance) => {
    scaleInstance.paddingLeft = 0;
    scaleInstance.paddingRight = 0;
  }
}
```